# Confusion with Ruby "Catch/Throw" construct

Tags: ruby

```
class Test
  def foo
    throw(:label, foo)
    "should never get here"
  end

  def bar
    "bar"
  end
end

test = Test.new
```

Now I tried the below:

```
puts("bar -> " + catch(:label) {test.bar})
```

and got :

```
bar -> bar
=> nil
```

Now when I tried:

```
puts("foo -> " + catch(:label) {test.foo})
```

I expected that i would get `nil` but actually got the below:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
Maybe IRB bug!
```

I am unable to explain myself why this. Could anyone help me for the same?

Comment: Why did you expect to get `nil`?

Comment: Why are you calling foo recursively in your throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop happens outside the throw/catch.

```
def foo
  throw(:label, foo) # <-
  "should never get here"
end
```

The value returned has to be generated first, no lazy eval there. So
it calls foo again, and you have your infinite recursion without any
stopping point. If you want nil, use

```
def foo
  throw(:label, nil) # <-
  "should never get here"
end
```

Comment: I am really in the dark still. Why `puts("bar -> " + catch(:label) {test.bar})` didn't throw exception,rather produce the error?

Comment: I didn't get you- what `come again`?

Comment: Because the crash occurs on any call to foo. Try calling just `puts(test.foo)` and it'll still happen.